# How to isolate two sessions while loading same webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Now suppose I have two `BrowserWindows` with two different sessions (say set by `session.fromPartition('s1')` and `session.fromPartition('s2')`), I assume the `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` method would apply separately to these two `BrowserWindows` as the sessions they are using are different. Also, none of these two sessions are `session.defaultSession` in this case.

But if I do

```
let s1 = session.fromPartition('persist:p1');
let s2 = session.fromPartition('persist:p2');
w1 = new BrowserWindow({ width: 640, height: 480, webPreferences: { session: s1 }});
w2 = new BrowserWindow({ width: 640, height: 480, webPreferences: { session: s2 }});
```

And change the `s1.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` to block all outgoing requests, nothing really gets blocked. Instead if I play with `session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` all requests (including s2!) somehow are stopped perfectly. Does this mean the custom sessions I set do not take effect? If so, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `webPreferences: { partition: 'persist:p1' }`?

Comment: @Tim yes from what I understand in the code snippet I posted `s1 = session.fromPartition('persist:p1')` is basically the same as what you show here, correct?

Comment: it **should** be... In the app user data directory, can you see the sessions being created in the `persist` directory?